# Streams read(0) instruction

Tags: node.js, stream

There is a code I found here https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook which reads 3 bytes from stream. And I do not understand how it works.

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
    var buf = process.stdin.read(3);
    console.log(buf);
    process.stdin.read(0);
});
```

Being called like this:

```
(echo abc; sleep 1; echo def; sleep 1; echo ghi) | node consume.js
```

It returns:

```
<Buffer 61 62 63>
<Buffer 0a 64 65>
<Buffer 66 0a 67>
<Buffer 68 69 0a>
```

First of all, why do I need this `.read(0)` thing? Isn't stream has a buffer where the rest of data is stored until I request it by `.read(size)`? But without `.read(0)` it'll print

```
<Buffer 61 62 63>
<Buffer 0a 64 65>
<Buffer 66 0a 67>
```

Why?

The second is these `sleep 1` instructions. If I call the script without it

```
(echo abc; echo def; echo ghi) | node consume.js
```

It'll print

```
<Buffer 61 62 63>
<Buffer 0a 64 65>
```

no matter will I use `.read(0)` or not. I don't understand this completely. What logic is used here to print such a result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about what exactly the author of https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook tried to show using the read(0) approach, but IMHO this is the correct approach:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function () {
  let buf;
  // Every time when the stream becomes readable (it can happen many times), 
  // read all available data from it's internal buffer in chunks of any necessary size.
  while (null !== (buf = process.stdin.read(3))) {
    console.dir(buf);
  }
});
```

You can change the chunk size, pass the input either with sleep or without it...

Answer (score 3):

I happened to learn NodeJS stream module these days. Here are some comments inside [Readable.prototype.read](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L372) function:

```
// if we're doing read(0) to trigger a readable event, but we
// already have a bunch of data in the buffer, then just trigger
// the 'readable' event and move on.
```

It said that after called `.read(0)`, `stream` would just trigger (using the `process.nextTick`) another `readable` event if `stream` was not ended.

```
function emitReadable(stream) {
  // ...
  process.nextTick(emitReadable_, stream);
  // ...
}
```