# Readable Streams and read(0)

Tags: node.js, stream

The following is an excerpt from the [stream-handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) by James Halliday (aka substack):

> Here's an example of using .read(n) to buffer stdin into 3-byte
>   chunks:
>
> ```
> process.stdin.on('readable', function () {
>     var buf = process.stdin.read(3);
>     console.dir(buf);
> });
> ```
>
> Running this example gives us incomplete data!
>
> ```
> $ (echo abc; sleep 1; echo def; sleep 1; echo ghi) | node consume1.js 
> <Buffer 61 62 63>
> <Buffer 0a 64 65>
> <Buffer 66 0a 67>
> ```
>
> This is because there is extra data left in internal buffers and we
>   need to give node a "kick" to tell it that we are interested in more
>   data past the 3 bytes that we've already read. A simple .read(0) will
>   do this:
>
> ```
> process.stdin.on('readable', function () {
>     var buf = process.stdin.read(3);
>     console.dir(buf);
>     process.stdin.read(0);
> });
> ```
>
> Now our code works as expected in 3-byte chunks!
>
> ```
> $ (echo abc; sleep 1; echo def; sleep 1; echo ghi) | node consume2.js 
> <Buffer 61 62 63>
> <Buffer 0a 64 65>
> <Buffer 66 0a 67>
> <Buffer 68 69 0a>
> ```

When I change the example to 2-byte read chunks, it breaks - presumably because the internal buffer still has data queued up. But that wouldn't happen if read(0) kicked off a 'readable' event each time it was called. Looks like it only happens after all the input is finished.

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function () {
    var buf = process.stdin.read(2);
    console.dir(buf);
    process.stdin.read(0);
});
```

What does this code do under the hood? It seems like read(0) queues another 'readable' event, but only at the end of input. I tried reading through the readable stream source, but it's pretty heavy-lifting. Does anyone know how this example works?

Comment: The streams docs (official and otherwise) seem surprisingly like black-magic to me. Have been trying to get my head around this stuff for a week

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729449/streams-read0-instruction/45612443#45612443.